# Failed CSRF token verification in Mezzanine with captcha form

Tags: python, django, captcha, mezzanine

I have been trying to set up a test version of a captcha form using the Django CMS, Mezzanine. It displays the captcha, but when I submit the form I get the error:

Forbidden (403)

CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.

Help

Reason given for failure:

```
CSRF token missing or incorrect.
```

In general, this can occur when there is a genuine Cross Site Request Forgery, or when Django's CSRF mechanism has not been used correctly. For POST forms, you need to ensure:

```
Your browser is accepting cookies.
The view function uses RequestContext for the template, instead of Context.
In the template, there is a {% csrf_token %} template tag inside each POST form that targets an internal URL.
If you are not using CsrfViewMiddleware, then you must use csrf_protect on any views that use the csrf_token template tag, as well as those that accept the POST data.

You're seeing the help section of this page because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and only the initial error message will be displayed.
You can customize this page using the CSRF_FAILURE_VIEW setting.
```

The behavior is the same with Firefox and Chrome (with or without incognito). I am using Python 3.4, Django 1.6.7, and Mezzanine 3.1.0. I have tried to fix the problem in several ways:
1) My html template:

```
<body>
    <h3>Captcha</h3>
    <form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input name="item_text" id="id_new_item" placeholder="Enter item">
        <br>
        {{ form.captcha }}
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</body>
```

2) In my settings.py file:

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    ...
    "django.core.context_processors.csrf",
)
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    ...
    "django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware",
)
```

3) In my captcha_test.views.py:

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_protect
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.http import HttpResponse

from captcha_test.forms import CaptchaTestForm 

@csrf_protect
def captcha_page(request):
    if request.POST:
        form = CaptchaTestForm(request.post)
        if form.is_valid():
            human = True
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
    else:
        form = CaptchaTestForm()
    return render_to_response('captcha.html', locals())
```

My forms.py file, if this helps at all:

```
from django import forms
from captcha.fields import CaptchaField

class CaptchaTestForm(forms.Form):
    item_text = forms.CharField()
    captcha = CaptchaField()
```

Any insights? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must ensure that:

> The view function uses `RequestContext` for the template, instead of `Context`.

But you use:

```
return render_to_response('captcha.html', locals())
```

And, from the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#render-to-response) to `render_to_response`:

> By default, the template will be rendered with a `Context` instance (filled with values from dictionary). If you need to use context processors, render the template with a `RequestContext` instance instead.

So adding `context_instance=RequestContext(request)` should solve the problem.